# jQuery validate, specific errorClass placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would simply like too know how to specificly add the errorClass to an element.
I'm using bootstrap-select to stylise my selects.
This hides the select element and creates a div, and jQuery validate adds the errorClass to the select element and not the div (makes sense).

How can I specifically say to that all selects, the errorClass should be on the div ? I'm guessing with highlight, but I can't seem to find how to do it only on one element.

Comment: Does the `errorPlacement` option do what you want?

Comment: Nope, i'm using errorPlacement to place the error messages. What I need here is too place the error class (the one that highlights the elements) that I've renamed to "invalid".

Comment: How about `errorClassContainer`?

Comment: I can't seem to find that function in the jquery validate documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of `errorContainer` or `errorLabelContainer`, but I don't think either of them solves your problem. I think you'll have to use `highlight`. I don't think you can use it on just one element, it will need to check the element and do the custom highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change where the `error` and `valid` classes are applied, you would have to specify customized `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.

These are the default functions in use.  Edit as needed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        // other rules & options,
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if (element.type === "radio") {
                this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            } else {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**jsFiddle DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/U3L73/**

I've applied colors to the default CSS classes only for illustration.

Answer (score 1):

showErrors function can be used. I do use it (bootstrap 3) to set **has-error** class to the **form-group** item, so it highlights all elements in form-group instead of just the input.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
    $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
        var $element = $(value);
        $element.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    });


    $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
        var $element = $(error.element);
        $element.closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    });
});
```